# How do I get the data from UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) in my app and I don't want to save the selected fullScreenImage to my array because if i selected 40 iPad images then that is not good.

I want to get data from `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` from the dict of method `- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info`.

I have tried:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [info objectAtIndex:count];            

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]]]];//UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]]] );
        NSLog(@"length %d",[data length]);
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

However, every time I am getting 0 bytes. I have tried with all the answers available in forum but no use.

Can anyone answer this please?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` returns `NSURL` object not the string object. Please change your code to -

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];
NSLog(@"length %d",[data length]);
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

`UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` returns `NSURL` object for `Assets Library`, so you can get image as -

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary assetForURL:[[self.imagedata objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData may be what you want
    [data writeToFile:photoFile atomically:YES];//you can save image later
} failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
}];
```

**Note: ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in iOS 9.**

Comment: thanks for your reply...i tried like that also even though in my log i am getting length as 0 "2012-05-29 18:32:13.536 myapp[1793:707] length 0"

Comment: it is 0 because UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL return NSURL object for Assets Library. so you need to use Assets Library to get image from this url. As - NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]; ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) { ... } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) { ... }];

Comment: For what it's worth ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in iOS 9. I have added an additional answer below.

Comment: @Jessedc, thanks for notification, i added a note for deprecation in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

This question ranks well on Google for `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` so I thought I'd add the correct way to use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` in **iOS9 and later as [ALAssetLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/) has been deprecated** in favour of the Photos Framework.

The correct way to access the photo using `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` provided in the info dictionary from [imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) is via Photos Kit [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html).

A basic implementation of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` utilising Photos Framework to fetch the UIImage would look something like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        guard let info = info, let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL else {
            // Using sourceType .Camea will end up in here as there is no UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL
            picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {}
            return
        }

        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([url], options: nil)
        if let photo = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(photo, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) {
                image, info in
                // At this point you have a UIImage instance as image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will not process callbacks when sourceType is `.Camera` since as the info dictionary does not contain `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

Comment: Note `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is deprecated in iOS 11.0 too, so one might use condition `NSString *infoKey;

            if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
                infoKey = UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset;
            } else {
                infoKey = UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL;
            }`

Comment: PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs is now deprecated as well.

Answer (score 1):

in ELCImagePickers "Selected assets" you can do

```
-(void)selectedAssets:(NSArray*)_assets {

"... your code .?.?."

    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(ALAsset *asset in _assets) {

        NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [workingDictionary setObject:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

".. any other properties you need ?"

        [returnArray addObject:workingDictionary];

    }
}
```

Then in your  other class to save from array

```
- (void) importImagesFromArray:(NSArray *)_images toFolder:(NSString *)folderPath
{
   if ([_images count] > 0) {

    //... YOUR CODE HERE FOR CHECKING YOUR ARRAY...Maybe a loop or something//
    //
    //
    //

    //ex:

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in _images) {



        [library assetForURL:[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){

                     //You Can Use This

                     UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]
                                                             scale:1.0
                                                       orientation:[[asset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue]];

                     //[....save image blah blah blah...];

                     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

                     ////// OR YOU CAN USE THIS////////////////////

                     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                     Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
                     NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
                     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData may be what you want
                     [data writeToFile:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Some Filename You Need To Assign"] atomically:YES];


                 }

                failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                    NSLog(@"Error saving image");

                }];

        // Dont forget to release library

    }
}
}
```