# How to get the url of sending an image in IOS application

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am working with an IOS application in which when i selected an image from IPhone simulator i want to take the URL(url Path) for that image .when i am trying to do it with my below code i get an array of url and not getting the specific string value from that array .Please help me that in which way i am able to retrieve that url for the image only not the array which i am getting with me code.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
            NSString *fileName = [representation filename];
            NSLog(@"fileName : %@",fileName);
        };

        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:nil];
        NSLog(@"ALAssetsLibrary : %@",assetslibrary);
```

Please give me the solution that how can i retrieve the url for that image?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question? I did not understood where you are getting an array and where you are trying to access image url.

Comment: when i print imageURL it gives me the value like :                        imagepath : (
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=36BF5BC0-09A7-4F77-837D-460BD7DF2580&ext=JPG"   )                                           this is an array,but i want only string value so that when i upload this image with the incoming url i could upload it.
if u know the way plz let me know thank you!!

Comment: plz check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799605/how-to-get-the-data-from-uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl-ios-sdk