# UIImagePickerController returns bigger Image than the originial

Tags: ios, objective-c, size, jpeg, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an app that let the users choose photo from the gallery. The problem I am facing is very weird as the size of the photo(in terms of storage) changes when its picked up using UIImagePickerController.

In my case, I got a picture via air-drop. The image size is 8.7MB. but when I pick the same image via UIImagePickerController, it returns me the image of ~13MB.

**Note:** the resolution of the image remains the same([3024, 4032]).

I created a very simple app to test the thing. Here is sample code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

bool flag = true;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:picker
                           animated:YES
                         completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *temp  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1);
    NSLog(@"image: %lu", (unsigned long)temp.length);
    NSLog(@"image: [%lu, %lu]", (unsigned long)chosenImage.size.width, (unsigned long)chosenImage.size.height);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                               completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

[this is the link to the app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2ruuywao1v32oa/Camera.zip?dl=0), in case you want to test it for yourself.

The zip file also contains the sample photos.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a computation that states what you expect to be equal to what.

Comment: this answer solves the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475923/1120688

Answer (score 0):

This is because you get the image uncompressed from the picker (as a UIImage). You then convert it to jpeg with UIImageJPEGRepresentation() and you are passing in 1.0 as the compression quality which is highest quality (least compression). If you pass a lower number like 0.5 for the quality the resulting data will be smaller. See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation?language=objc

**update**

If you want the original file data you can use UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, see here: [How do I get the data from UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799605/how-do-i-get-the-data-from-uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl)

Comment: Your first answer was not valid. Since I myself don't want to touch the image by compressing it or anything. I solved my problem using http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475923/1120688

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
    {
        UIImage* chosenImage = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        NSLog(@"Image Size Width %f  Height %f",chosenImage.size.width,chosenImage.size.height);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480));
        [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
        UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSLog(@"image Size h %f  Width %f",[image size].height, [image size].width);

    }
```