# why image size from UIImagePickerController is larger than original size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried to read similar problem in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377960/uiimagepickercontroller-returns-bigger-image-than-the-originial) but it doesn't solve my issue, because the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799605/how-do-i-get-the-data-from-uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl/38475923#38475923) is deprecated.

so I have an image, the size is only 57 Kb on the gallery. I want the user pick an image from their gallery, but the problem is, the image picked from gallery become far larger than original image in disk, from 57 Kb to be 560 Kb. here is the code I use

```
   func showChooseImageFromGalleryAlert() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
        
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Poster", message: "Choose your best poster", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        let actionPhotoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Gallery gallery", style: .default) { (action) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        
        actionSheet.addAction(actionPhotoLibrary)
        actionSheet.addAction(actionCancel)
        
        actionSheet.view.tintColor = UIColor(named: ColorName.BRAND_COLOR)
        
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and the result is in here

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage  else {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        
        print("check size in Kb: \(getImageSizeInkB(image: image)!) Kb")

        // the image is far larger than original image in here
        // it becomes 560 Kb. 10 times bigger
        
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
       
        
        
    }
```

can I get the same size as the original image ?

Comment: Why don't you use Jpeg compression?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger because the image quality will be different if I compress it. and the compression process will be in the backend in my case, so I can get the same result both from Android and iOS. so I just need to send an original image